# glm::frustum vs glm::perspectiveFov

Tags: 3d, projection, glm, projection-matrix

When I use `glm::perspectiveFov(90.0f,512.0f,512.0f,1.0f,256.0f)` I receive a working perspective projection with 90° in both x and y, as seen below (camera is in center of cube, facing towards a side)
[image]

However, when I use `glm::frustum(-256.0f,256.0f,-256.0f,256.0f,1.0f,256.0f)` I receive something that is either scaled beyond recognition or some kind of 180° view?
[image]

I would expect atleast a square projection.
What am I missing or doing wrong?

```cpp
auto projection = glm::perspectiveFov(to_rad(90.0f), float(cube_resolution), float(cube_resolution), 1.0f/1024.0f, 256.0f);
//projection = glm::frustum(-float(cube_resolution),float(cube_resolution),-float(cube_resolution),float(cube_resolution),1/1024.0f,256.0f);
auto view_projection = projection * view;
```

Comment: Try printing both matrices. Then you can see (and show us) how they differ more directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `perspectiveFov`, the angle of spread in the vertical direction is set by the `fov` parameter, and the horizontal angle is related to it by the width and height parameters:

```
fov_horizontal_radians = 2 * atan(tan(fov_vertical_radians/2) * width / height)
```

(Docs aren't as explicit as I'd like about whether that vertical `fov` parameter is the full bottom-to-top angle, or half that - the center-to-top angle. I've seen APIs use both these conventions. I wrote the above assuming it's the full bottom-to-top angle, but if I got that wrong, you can delete the two 2s to get the correct formula for the half angle version)

You can see here that all that matters is the aspect radio of width:height - their absolute magnitudes don't affect the shape of the frustum, since that's fixed by our `fov` angle.

`frustum` is different. Because we don't specify any angles in that form, we need to work out the shape of the frustum from the `left`/`right`/`top`/`bottom` values - and that means their absolute magnitudes matter, not only their ratios. In this case, these are taken to be coordinates on the near clipping plane, which in your case is a distance of 1 from the camera. So the closer the near clipping plane, the wider the frustum spreads.

If `near = 1`, `left = -256`, and `right = 256`, then our total horizontal field of view is...

```
fov_left  = atan(-left/near);                  // 1.567 rad =  89.776° 
fov_right = atan(right/near);                  // 1.567 rad =  89.776°
fov_horizontal_radians = fov_left + fov_right; // 3.134 rad = 179.552°
```

So that's why you're getting something more like a 180 degree field of view with your `frustum` code.

To get just a 90 degree field of view, scale down your arguments to the size of the near clipping plane at the narrow end of the frustum, eg.

```
glm::frustum(-near,near,-near,near,near,256.0f)
```

That means to reach the top edge of the near plane, we go `near` units along the view direction and `near` units up (rise = run means this is 45°). To reach the bottom edge of the near plane, we do the same but down instead, so that's another 45°. Adding those up, that's a 90° field of view vertically, and the same argument goes for the horizontal axis.